# Tag Badges and Bounties

Tags: discussion

A tag badge has two hurdles: 'answers provided' and 'score'.

An upvoted answer will be accounted for in both hurdles: the 'answers provided' count is incremented; and the 'score' is incremented.  Each additional upvote on the answer increments the 'score'.

When the answer is awarded a bounty, what does the accounting software do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bounty consists solely of a reputation reward, much like an acceptance mark. It does not increment the total score like an upvote does.